# Time trial racing is superior to road racing, because it is more honest

Tags: road-bike, racing, time-trial

Is TT racing is a more honest form of racing?

Road bike races are just a bunch of guys all crowded together trying to hide from the air behind the guy in front of them. Not showing honest speeds I think. What do you think?

Comment: TT and Road racing are only about pushing out watts, its brute force and requiring no skill and no consequences (unless you call loosing a consequence). If you want real racing, Downhill MTBing is where its at.  :)

Comment: No offense, but "not honest" is typically what a loser in a race says to a winner. Adhere to the rules, get better and win; do not whine about honesty — that is the way to winning.

Comment: Voting to close the question as mostly opinion-based. @rob1234, if you want to have constructive conversations on this questions-and-answers-typed site, please read its rules. Starting from the [Tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) is recommended for beginners.

Comment: If we have people discussing how to put the toilet paper roll or if you pour tea in milk or milk in tea...

Answer (score 2):

Any meathead can race a TT - "Grog strong! Grog stomp hard on crank. Grog go fast." I don't even know why they bother doing it outside - they might as well do the sport on a trainer.

Road racing takes strategy and forces riders to use their brains as well as their fitness and endurance.

Answer (score 1):

You could argue that any lightweight could race in a 'normal' race 'Please don't let the guy in front realise I haven't done a turn in an hour', but that would be unnecessarily imflamatory.
The question should be rearranged to idendify the required outcome.
If the question is:

> "Should TT riding be considered as a truer representation of a riders' speed over a certain distance, which can be measured objectively?"

Then the answer would be 'yes' .

If the question is :

> "Should TT riding be considered as 'superior' to normal road racing as it can't be measured objectively?

Then the answer is 'no', as the practice of cycling in a bunch is highly subjective, and requires a lot of skill other than pedal power and aerodynamics to win.

In my personal opinion, TT riding (and more specifically static trainer riding) is a more honest form of competition, but it's less exciting. Can you imagine all stages of the Tour de France as TT?

Comment: it would be a lot slower tour de france if they did

Answer (score 1):

TT Racing is all about watts and who can afford the best aeronautical engineers to squeeze out every piece of drag.

Why have them on a road? Stick everyone on a WattBike and weigh the results with a coefficient that favours of the teams with the biggest budgets. Job done. :)